# Reformatting MySQL table as grid

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting

I have a table for holding translations.  It is laid out as follows:

```
id | iso | token | content
-----------------------------------------------
 1 | GB  | test1 | Test translation 1 (English)
 2 | GB  | test2 | Test translation 2 (English)
 3 | FR  | test1 | Test translation 1 (French)
 4 | FR  | test2 | Test translation 2 (French)

// etc
```

For the translation management tool to go along with the table I need to output it in something more like a spreadsheet grid:

```
 token          | GB                           | FR                          | (other languages) --> 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 test1          | Test translation 1 (English) | Test translation 1 (French) |
 test2          | Test translation 1 (French)  | Test translation 2 (French) |
 (other tokens) |                              |                             |
       |        |                              |                             |
       |        |                              |                             |
       V        |                              |                             |
```

I thought this would be easy, but it turned out to be far more difficult than I expected!

After a lot of searching and digging around I did find group_concat, which for the specific case above I can get to work and generate the output I'm looking for:

```
select 
    token, 
    group_concat(if (iso = 'FR', content, NULL)) as 'FR',
    group_concat(if (iso = 'GB', content, NULL)) as 'GB'
from 
    translations
group by token;
```

However, this is, of course, totally inflexible.  It only works for the two languages I have specified so far.  The instant I add a new language I have to manually update the query to take it into account.

I need a generalized version of the query above, that will be able to generate the correct table output without having to know anything about the data stored in the source table.

Some sources claim you can't easily do this in MySQL, but I'm sure it must be possible.  After all, this is the sort of thing databases exist for in the first place.

Is there a way of doing this?  If so, how?

Comment: There's no generic query to achieve what you want. You would have to manually add a `GROUP_CONCAT` or a `JOIN` for each language.

Comment: or just do the transformation on the client side...

Comment: We have actually taken our translation system from a "grid" style system to a more flexible system like you are moving from. We found the manual changes to the table are more regular than anticipated. At first we figured less rows would be better but this equals more work, much more work as a "grid". My suggestion is to keep it as-is unless you have a compelling reason to change.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not planning to change the table layout, I'm just trying to come up with an SQL query like the one I've given that can generate an output in the format of the second table using the first table as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of mysql limitations, I need to do something like this on query side and in 1 query, I would do it like this:

**query:**

```
select token, group_concat(concat(iso,'|',content)) as contents
from translations
group by token
```

**"token";"contents"**

> "test1";"GB|Test translation 1 (English),FR|Test translation 1
>   (French),IT|Test translation 1 (Italian)" "test2";"GB|Test translation
>   2 (English),FR|Test translation 2 (French),IT|Test translation 2
>   (Italian)"

Than While I am binding rows I could split from comma to rows and split from pipe for header..

Answer (score 2):

What you seek is often called a dynamic crosstab wherein you dynamically determine the columns in the output. Fundamentally, relational databases are not designed to dynamically determine the schema. The best way to achieve what you want is to use a middle-tier component to build the crosstab SQL statement similar to what you have shown and then execute that.

Comment: Seems weird that SQL doesn't support this, it is after all supposed to be a tool for building reports from data.

Comment: @GordonM - Once you understand why, the reason is clear. Columns represent the schema of the table. The fundamental presumption with relational databases is that the schema is known at design time. Databases are *NOT* tools for building reports. Databases are tools for storing and managing data (primarily facts). Reporting engines are tools for building reports and often they *do* provide dynamic crosstab functionality.